# Diff two multidimensional arrays in PHP

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, diff, scheduling

I have to make some piece of code for scheduling software which shows whether the instructor is available or not.

So I have made the following (month) period:

```
    $begin = new \DateTime('first day of this month');
    $end = new \DateTime('last day of this month');

    $dailyInterval = new \DateInterval('P1D');
    $dailyPeriod = new \DatePeriod($begin, $dailyInterval, $end);
    $data = [];

    /** @var \DateTime $date */
    foreach($dailyPeriod as $date)
    {
        $currentDate = $date->format('Y-m-d');
        $start = new \DateTime("$currentDate 08:00");
        $finish = new \DateTime("$currentDate 20:00");

        $appointmentInterval = new \DateInterval($appointmentVariant->getInterval());
        $appointmentPeriod = new \DatePeriod($start, $appointmentInterval, $finish);

        /** @var \DateTime $duration */
        foreach($appointmentPeriod as $duration)
        {
            $endDate = clone $duration;
            $data['availability'][$currentDate][] = [
                'start' => $duration->format('H:i:s'),
                'end' => $endDate->modify('+90 minutes')->format('H:i:s')
            ];
        }
    }
```

The output of this is as follows:

```
availability: [
    '2016-12-01': [
        0: ['start': '08:00:00', 'end': '09:30:00'],
        1: ['start': '09:30:00', 'end': '11:00:00'],
        2: ['start': '11:00:00', 'end': '12:30:00'],
        3: ['start': '12:30:00', 'end': '14:00:00'],
        4: ['start': '14:00:00', 'end': '15:30:00'],
        5: ['start': '15:30:00', 'end': '17:00:00'],
        6: ['start': '17:00:00', 'end': '18:30:00'],
        7: ['start': '18:30:00', 'end': '20:00:00']
    ]
]
```

But now we have to get out from the database when instructor is unavailable (this can come from multiple sources, appointments, vacations, recurring events etc), so finally we have the array as the above one, but with unavailability:

```
unavailability: [
    '2016-12-01': [
        0: ['start': '14:30:00', 'end': '16:30:00'],
        1: ['start': '18:00:00', 'end': '18:20:00'],
    ]
]
```

And now is the question, how to diff those two arrays to get one final when the instructor is available? It's pretty hard to loop over available dates and times and then unavailable dates and times.

The diff should give me back the following result (DEL = to delete):

```
availability: [
    '2016-12-01': [
        0: ['start': '08:00:00', 'end': '09:30:00'],
        1: ['start': '09:30:00', 'end': '11:00:00'],
        2: ['start': '11:00:00', 'end': '12:30:00'],
        3: ['start': '12:30:00', 'end': '14:00:00'],
        DEL 4: ['start': '14:00:00', 'end': '15:30:00'],
        DEL 5: ['start': '15:30:00', 'end': '17:00:00'],
        DEL 6: ['start': '17:00:00', 'end': '18:30:00'],
        7: ['start': '18:30:00', 'end': '20:00:00']
    ]
]
```

Does anybody know the most efficient way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Try splitting the day into 10 minute blocks. You can then unset these depending on the unavailability from the database.

You could then output the start and end using the min/max values for that day.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you hawx of the tip. You were right, splitting the day into 10 minute blocks is way easier to handle

Answer (score 0):

```
$unavailability = your unavailability array();
$availability   = your availability array();
//this loop will procedd how much your availability in your ex : will be 1
foreach($availability as $key=>$val)
{
    if(isset($unavailability[$key]))
    {
       //6 times loop
       foreach($val as $new_key => $new_val)
       {
            2 times loop
            foreach($unavailability[$key] as $unavailkey => $unavail_val)
            {
                if($new_val['start'] >= $unavail_val['start'])
                {
                   unset($new_val)
                }
                else
                {
                   continue;
                }
            }
       }
    }
    else
    {
       continue;
    } 

}
```

its quite tricky and can make you face performance issue if your design result data its too complicated.

its can be done with using assosiative array too , but the code will become dirty

good luck

Comment: Thanks Evinn, it gave me some idea indeed. The biggest problem I was facing was performance issue. So, in the end i had to rethink whole idea of diff.